# using multiple mclapply, parLapply

Tags: r, mclapply

I am trying to chain multiple mclapply/parLapply:

```
my_function<-function(x){
do something;
mclapply()
}
```

Then I vary my x:

```
mclapply(1:100,function(i)(function(x[i])),mc.cores=60)
```

The problem is that I often get the following error:

> scheduled cores 3, 57, 54, 8, 23, 17, 53, 18, 22, 28, 41, 25, 30 encountered errors in user code, all values of the jobs will be affected

The interesting thing is that I am not getting errors, if I am running this on my ubuntu machine but I am getting this error when I run this on CentOS machine. Similar things happen when I perform the second step using parLapply

I have also tried:

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(no_cores)
clusterExport(cl,c("function_main_simulation","a1","a2","no_cores"))
system.time(parLapply(cl,1:10000,function(i)(function_main_simulation(a1,a2))))
stopCluster(cl)
```

But again I am getting some interesting errors.